# Create a copy of virtualenv locally without pip install

Tags: python, pip, copy, virtualenv

Sometime there is a need to create a copy of exiting **virtualenv** to test extra features of our project.

In such a case we need to create a copy of the existing environment and add few more requirements.

One of the way to create a copy of existing virtualenv is mentioned below:

```
# while using existing virtualenv
(oldenv): pip freeze > requirements.txt

# after creating and logged-in to new virtualenv
(newenv): pip install -r requirements.txt

# where requirements.txt is the same file created using (oldenv)
```

But I personally do not prefer this way. Why?? **Because of installing the same packages which are already there which we can re-use.** Re-using or say copying will not only reduce the extra time and effort but will also reduce the Internet bandwidth usage to none, specially for limited and slow Internet users.

Cool! Then what are the other ways to create a copy of existing **virtualenv** locally?

I know two other ways which I'm mentioning below. Hope these will be helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**First way to create a copy of existing virtualenv, say `ProjectAenv`:**

1. Copy the ProjectAenv to some other name or directory:

   ```
   cp -R /home/sk/Path1/ProjectAenv /home/sk/Path2/ProjectBenv
   ```

   where `/home/sk/Path1/ProjectAenv` is the absolute path of the virtualenv **ProjectAenv**
2. Then open the `activate` file of newly copied **ProjectBenv** using your preferred editor:

   ```
   gedit /home/sk/Path2/ProjectBenv/bin/activate
   ```
3. Find the line **VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/sk/Path1/ProjectAenv"** and replace it with:

   ```
   VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/sk/Path2/ProjectBenv"
   ```

   Save and close the file.

Thats it!! Your new environment **ProjectBenv** is copied from **ProjectAenv** and ready to use. I'm using this way for a long time and never got any issues yet, although I recommend the 2nd way of copying.

**Second way to create a copy of existing virtualenv(Recommended)**:

1. Download **virtualenv-clone**:

   ```
   wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv-clone/virtualenv-clone-0.2.6.tar.gz
   tar -zxvf virtualenv-clone-0.2.6.tar.gz
   cd virtualenv-clone-0.2.6
   ```
2. Install **virtualenv-clone** inside any virtualenv environment:

   ```
   virtualenv newenv            # create a new environment. You can use any existing one.
   source newenv/bin/activate   # login to newenv
   (newenv): python setup.py install  # install virtualenv-clone in newenv
   # be sure that you are inside the directory "virtualenv-clone-0.2.6"
   ```

   `virtualenv-clone` will be installed inside newenv.
3. Now while logged-in as newenv we can create a copy of any existing environment. For example creating the copy of ProjectAenv:

   ```
   (newenv): virtualenv-clone ProjectAenv ProjectBenv 
   (newenv): deactivate             # to come out from newenv.
   ```

Please comment for any suggestions or changes.

Comment: The first approach is bad.  In that approach, you just changed the location of virtual environnent. But the `pip` command has a shebang which uses the python location while building. Therefore, you wont be able to run `pip` if you go about copying like Method 1.  Other shell scripts that are in you `bin` folder will not work as well for the same reason.

Comment: For completeness I would like to add a comment to the answer of @SauravKumar: Also the second method utilising the package `virtualenv-clone` results in an incorrect path to the *old* python executable in the shebang line.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add to the manual method of @SauravKumar. Fixing the path in the `activate` script is necessary, but not sufficient. You also need to fix the path in other scripts like `pip`, `pip2`, etc.

The easiest thing to do is search for your path inside the virtual environment `bin` folder like:

```
root@www:/var/www/app/venv/bin# grep "/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv" * -R
activate:VIRTUAL_ENV="/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv"
activate.csh:setenv VIRTUAL_ENV "/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv"
activate.fish:set -gx VIRTUAL_ENV "/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv"
django-admin:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
django-admin.py:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
easy_install:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
easy_install-2.7:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
pbr:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
pip:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
pip2:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
pip2.7:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
python-config:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python
sqlformat:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
wheel:#!/tmp/app/HadithHouseWebsite/venv/bin/python2.7
```

Then go through these files and change the ones you need. Mostly you need to change the `activate*` files and `pip*` files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Running the following from within the bin directory will make the changes. `sed -i "s,{OLD_PATH},{NEW_PATH}," *`